# Please advise a worthy book on multithreading with boost.thread or C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost-thread

Which book is worth buying, for your opinion? I'm generally familiar with multithreading concepts, OpenMP, basic WinAPI threading. I want now to learn to use new std::thread or boost.thread effectively - I'm unfamiliar with things like atomics, conditional variables, etc.

Comment: I doubt there are many books describing C++11, as it was just made into a standard a little earlier this year. Though there might be a few describing the proposals.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: I know, but the draft was here for a lo-o-o-ong time,so I won't be surprised if there are books available. Couldn't find, though, so you might be right.

Comment: I would suggest to also look into Posix threads. At least to understand the common concepts and the differences with Windows threads.

Comment: [C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770) will be out by the end of the year. The author, [Anthony Williams](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5597/anthony-williams), is a fellow StackOverflow user, the author of the `just::thread` library, and maintainer of Boost.Thread.

Comment: William's book is *pretty* much out already as it is part of the Manning early access editions. I purchased it online about a year ago and it hasn't changed since.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know this book but the title got my attention: [C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.manning.com/williams/). Perhaps it contains what you need, just take a look at the preview. It has some information about C++11